# how to insert file from jsp in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

i am trying to insert data along with image file. image is not inserted on data but inside WEB-INF/resources/images. when i click submit button nothing is inserted.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<c:url 
value="/admin/addProduct"/>" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="productCode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productCode" name="productCode" 
      placeholder="product code">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName"
       placeholder="product name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productPrice" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productPrice" name="price" 
      placeholder="product price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Upload Image</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="prodImage">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Product</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**ProductController**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/addProduct", method= RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addNewProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") 
    Product products,BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("adding product");

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
      return "addProduct";
    }
    productService.saveProduct(products);

    MultipartFile productImage = products.getImage();
    String rootDir = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    path = Paths.get(rootDir+"//WEB-INF//resources//images//"+products.getId()+".png");
    if(productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("inside not null product image");
      try {
        productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
      }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("product image saving failed",ex);
      }
    }

    return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
  }
```

and my pom.xml looks like:-

my pom includes commons-fileupload and commons-io.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.itn</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ecommerce Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.
      PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/db.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.
      LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.
                  MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.itn</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.
      HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.
      DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.
      commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024000" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

i can insert form data (without file) successfully when i ignore `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`but whenever i include multipart in form and run in debug mode nothing appears. what am i missing here?

Comment: I guess you mean `uploading file` when you say `insert file` ?

Comment: Show your configuration. This might be related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773777/spring-file-upload-not-binding-to-model-attribute-object

Comment: Do you have implementation for DispatcherServlet initialisation which most application usually name something like 'MyApplicationWebInitialiser'? Please add that too in your post if you have @sagar limbu

Comment: please check applicationContext.xml

Comment: Please provide your Product class code

Comment: Check the input name to correspond with your Java Product image field for a good binding

Comment: the name in jsp file and Product class is prodImage. i dont think that is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to wire up a multipart resolver:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
    return resolver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload) spring tutorial, you should be adding `MultipartConfigElement` on start up of your servlet if you are using servlet of version > 3.0 (which I see you are from your `pom.xml`).

See "**3. With Servlet 3.0**" in the attached link of spring tutorial.

```
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(TMP_FOLDER, 
      MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE * 2, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE / 2);
```

After adding above in your Dispatcher servlet initialiser, you need to add bean of `StandardServletMultipartResolver` in your application config.

```
@Bean
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```